# Express : async, await : Cannot access 'result' before initialization

Tags: javascript, sql-server, api, rest, express

The login function uses the ExecuteSQL function is used to check whether a user exists? I'm getting the following error while I'm running this file. async await.

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'result' before initialization
> at /Users/naseefali/Documents/Projects/common_express_api/data/DL.js:100:25
> at async login (/Users/naseefali/Documents/Projects/common_express_api/data/DL.js:99:24)
> SELECT fUserPwd FROM tblUser WHERE fUserID ='ADMIN'
> {
> recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
> recordset: [ { fUserPwd: '006060061500675006630067300667' } ],
> output: {},
> rowsAffected: [ 1 ]
> }

Code

```
async function testConnection() {
    try {

        const pool = await getConnection();
        if (pool) {
            const result = await pool.request()
                .query('SELECT * FROM tblUser', function (err, sqlResult) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(sqlResult);
                    }
                });
        }
        else console.log(pool);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

async function ExecuteSQL(strSQL) {
    try {
        const pool = await getConnection();
        if (pool) {
            const result = await pool.request()
                .query(strSQL, async function (err, sqlResult) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(strSQL);
                        console.log(sqlResult);
                        return sqlResult;
                    }
                });
        }
        else console.log(pool);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};


async function login(strUID) {
    const strSQL = `SELECT fUserPwd FROM tblUser WHERE fUserID ='${strUID}'`;
    try {
        const result = await ExecuteSQL(strSQL).then(await function () {
            console.log(result);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

};

login('ADMIN');
```

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't return a value on then, and access result before assigning it

```js
 async function login(strUID) {
    const strSQL = `SELECT fUserPwd FROM tblUser WHERE fUserID ='${strUID}'`;
    try {
        const result = await ExecuteSQL(strSQL).then(await function () {
            console.log(result);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

 };
```

try change it to

```js
 const result = await ExecuteSQL(strSQL).then(function (data) {
  return data
 });
 console.log(result);
```

or just

```
 const result = await ExecuteSQL(strSQL);
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: with : const result = await ExecuteSQL(strSQL);
 console.log(result); it's still undefined..

Comment: with :  const result = await ExecuteSQL(strSQL).then(function (data) {
  return data
 });
 console.log(result); still it is undefined

Comment: sorry, I didn't point out that there's something wrong in function ExecuteSQL, inside this function you need to return result, you can have a look on Naseef Ali's answer

Answer (score 0):

here I'm just returning anything from ExecuteSQL.

I did

```
async function ExecuteSQL(strSQL) {
    try {
        const pool = await getConnection();
        //you don't need to check for the pool, because getConnection() will throw if there is an error 
        const result = await pool.request().query(strSQL);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};


async function login(strUID) {
    const strSQL = `SELECT fUserPwd FROM tblUser WHERE fUserID ='${strUID}'`;
    try {
        const result = await ExecuteSQL(strSQL);
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

};
```